# Not getting CLI Trace log DB2

Tags: db2, trace

Currently I am working on fixing an issue with the Java-DB2 connection leak. For which I require the *CLI Trace* logs. In my *db2cli.ini* I have added the below parameters, but still I am not getting the the trace logs.

```
    [COMMON]
    JDBCTrace=1
    JDBCTraceFlush=1
    JDBCTracePathName=C:\tracejdbc
```

Earlier we were using DB2 9.7 in which I was able to get the logs for the above changes. And now we are using *DB2 10.5.3*. I am trying it myself. Meanwhile it would be helpful on getting an Expert advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are confusing the *JDBC trace* and the *CLI trace*. To enable the JDBC trace in the JCC driver, which is the only one available in DB2 10.5, you need to set the JDBC connection properties [as described in the manual](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.java.doc/src/tpc/imjcc_cjvjcdig.html?lang=en), for example, via the JDBC URL:

```
String url = "jdbc:db2://my.host.com:50000/mydb" +
             ":traceFile=/tmp/jcc.trc;" +
             "traceLevel=" + com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2BaseDataSource.TRACE_DRDA_FLOWS + ";";
```

Various trace levels are [described here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.java.doc/src/tpc/imjcc_r0024939.html?lang=en).

Only the Type 2 JDBC driver will read `db2cli.ini`, so setting CLI properties has no effect if you are using Type 4 connectivity. Type 2 connectivity is deprecated an is not recommended for use.

Comment: @musstaccio Thanks for the efforts on explanation. I am trying to understand the configuration. But the options that I have added should have some effect right? As I see in the [link](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.cli.doc/doc/c0007882.html) those parameters seems to be valid. Why won't it have any effect?

Comment: As I said, the JCC driver _never reads_ `db2cli.ini`. The parameters there were for the Type 2 JDBC driver, which was deprecated long ago. You shouldn't be referring to the DB2 9.5 documentation if you use DB2 10.5.

Comment: @mustaccio The JCC driver has both a Type 2 driver and a Type 4 driver, depending on the JDBC URL you use.  (`jdbc:db2:mydb` = Type 2 and depends on the native DB2 Client libraries; `jdbc:db2://my.host.com:50000/mydb` = Type 4 and is pure Java)

Comment: @IanBjorhovde -- clarified the terminology, thanks.